# Two different GPUs in this machine

Tags: dual-gpu

I wonder if my computer configuration is capable of handling these two different GPUs, especially the PSU.

**Configuration:**

- Corsair CX600
- Intel i7 4770K 3.5
- 16GB Crucial Ballistix Elite DDR2 1866 CL9
- Gigabyte Radeon R9 280 WINDFORCE 3GB
- ASRock Z97 PRO4
- Crucial SSD CT256
- Hitachi HDT250
- WDC WD10EADS
- DVD DH16AASH

Can i add the MSI N550 GTX IT to use the cuda cores without problems?

Best Regards,
Diogo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You may add that card if your motherboard has an additional full PCI-E slot.**

You did not state the MB model.

Although physx still cause a lot of driver conflicts, some people do use secondary geforce cards for game phyxs.
If you want physx for games, add the card. If you want pure processing power for special applications, the radeon in your specs is better, no reason to add the secondary.

Comment: Hello Overmind and thanks for your answer! I just added the MB model. I need the cuda cores for 3D Rendering.

Comment: I see it has an additional PCIe 2.0 x16 port, so yes, you may add the card as secondary and use your rendering application.

Comment: And the PSU will take care of all components? Thats my main doubt..

Comment: Max power on 12A line is 480W, so yes, it's fine. Additionally, if your rendering engine uses the geforce, the radeon would be mostly idle. Games may use both, though. As long as you don't overclock, you will be ok.